# Fixing cropped Kable image in R

Tags: r, kableextra

I have the following table using `kableExtra` in R

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

sr <- c('Positive (+)','Positive (+)','Negative (-)','Positive (+)')
lr <- c('Positive (+)','Neutral','Negative (-)','Positive (+)')
d <- c('GDP Response to Positive','','CPI Response to Positive','')
s <- c('AS Shock','AD Shock','AS Shock','AD Shock')

data.frame(d,s,sr,lr) %>% 
  kable(col.names = c('','','Short Run Effect','Long Run Effect'),'html') %>% 
  kable_styling() %>% 
  row_spec(0, col = 'white', background = '#7c3042') %>% 
  footnote(general="<b>These signs represent prior expectations for the short and long run dynamics
           of variable responses to respective shocks, based on a conventional AS-AD framework<b>", escape = FALSE) %>% 
  column_spec(1:4,bold = T) %>% 
  save_kable(file = "table.png", density = 700)
```

For some odd reason, the table is slightly cropped off at the top when I save it. Any way to overcome this?

[image]

EDIT

Here is my session info

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Namibia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Namibia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Namibia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=English_Namibia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] magick_2.6.0      hrbrthemes_0.8.0  lubridate_1.7.9.2 readxl_1.3.1      tbl2xts_1.0.4     feasts_0.1.6     
 [7] fabletools_0.3.0  tsbox_0.2.1       tsibble_0.9.3     Rcpp_1.0.6        kableExtra_1.3.1  forcats_0.5.0    
[13] stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.3       purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.2       tibble_3.0.5     
[19] ggplot2_3.3.3     tidyverse_1.3.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-151               fs_1.5.0                   xts_0.12.1                 webshot_0.5.2             
 [5] httr_1.4.2                 tools_4.0.3                backports_1.2.1            R6_2.5.0                  
 [9] DBI_1.1.1                  colorspace_2.0-0           withr_2.4.0                tidyselect_1.1.0          
[13] processx_3.4.5             extrafontdb_1.0            curl_4.3                   compiler_4.0.3            
[17] cli_2.2.0                  rvest_0.3.6                pacman_0.5.1               xml2_1.3.2                
[21] sandwich_3.0-0             tseries_0.10-48            scales_1.1.1               lmtest_0.9-37             
[25] quadprog_1.5-8             callr_3.5.1                systemfonts_0.3.2          digest_0.6.27             
[29] foreign_0.8-81             rmarkdown_2.6              rio_0.5.16                 pkgconfig_2.0.3           
[33] htmltools_0.5.0            extrafont_0.17             dbplyr_2.0.0               highr_0.8                 
[37] rlang_0.4.9                TTR_0.24.2                 rstudioapi_0.13            quantmod_0.4.18           
[41] farver_2.0.3               generics_0.1.0             zoo_1.8-8                  jsonlite_1.7.2            
[45] distributional_0.2.1       zip_2.1.1                  car_3.0-10                 magrittr_2.0.1            
[49] munsell_0.5.0              fansi_0.4.2                gdtools_0.2.3              abind_1.4-5               
[53] lifecycle_0.2.0            stringi_1.5.3              carData_3.0-4              PerformanceAnalytics_2.0.4
[57] MASS_7.3-53                plyr_1.8.6                 grid_4.0.3                 parallel_4.0.3            
[61] strucchange_1.5-2          crayon_1.3.4               lattice_0.20-41            haven_2.3.1               
[65] hms_1.0.0                  knitr_1.30                 anytime_0.3.9              ps_1.5.0                  
[69] pillar_1.4.7               ggpubr_0.4.0               ggsignif_0.6.0             reshape2_1.4.4            
[73] codetools_0.2-18           reprex_0.3.0               urca_1.3-0                 glue_1.4.2                
[77] evaluate_0.14              vars_1.5-3                 data.table_1.13.6          modelr_0.1.8              
[81] vctrs_0.3.6                foreach_1.5.1              Rttf2pt1_1.3.8             cellranger_1.1.0          
[85] gtable_0.3.0               PortfolioAnalytics_1.1.0   assertthat_0.2.1           xfun_0.20                 
[89] openxlsx_4.2.3             broom_0.7.3                rstatix_0.6.0              viridisLite_0.3.0         
[93] iterators_1.0.13           ellipsis_0.3.1
```

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot, I've added my sessionInfo to my post, yes I do have magick installed. I'm just viewing the image in my png viewer on windows and I noticed it is slightly cropped off at the top. ```row_spec(0, angle = -45)``` doesn't work

Comment: @jared_mamrot yes it still crops off when i set the angle to -45. The problem still persists even when I detach the ```magick``` package

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry - I have no idea what the problem is - hopefully someone else with more domain-specific knowledge can work out the issue.

Comment: I executed your code and I cannot reproduce the error. We have the same R version, Platform and attached base packages. So I believe you should systematically try to detach packages and see if that helps. I would start with `hrbrthemes_0.8.0`, `tbl2xts_1.0.4`, `fabletools_0.3.0`,  `tsbox_0.2.1`.

Comment: @sa90210 did you ever manage to fix this? I have the same problem